# What happened to my cornbread? Please help

Tags: baking

please help me. My cornbread sunk in the middle.what did I do wrong?

Comment: Hi.  It might be helpful to your question to add in some details - like what recipe you were using, how you made it, when it sunk in the middle (or when you noticed), things like that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a long shot, but did you by any chance just make this recipe up yourself? Or modify a good recipe?  This happens to my baking experiments a lot; I think when my batter starts out too liquid & doesn't cook all the way in the middle of the pan, or it has too much leavening (baking soda/powder) which causes over fluffing, then sink-age when the baked product isn't strong enough to sustain all that air as it cools.